# Meaning of "Frankie Ears" in "The Intuitionist"

Tags: colson-whitehead, the-intuitionist

> One prosaic gent outside the room, went by the name of "Frankie Ears" on
> account of the vestigial, flaplike things on the sides of his face

This is from *The Intuitionist* by Colson Whitehead. In "Frankie Ears", is Frankie a name of person and Ears his nickname?

Answer (score 2):

"Frankie Ears" is his nickname. "Frankie" may or may not be part of his given name. It's not uncommon for a nickname to pick up bits that have no particular relevance except to the person coining the nickname. I'm having difficulty placing any case in my own personal experience, but as a general thing, you'll sometimes see terms like "He's a regular Joe Sixpack" to refer to someone who's really common, or a generic ethnic name might get appended, like someone calling a pokey person of Mexican descent "Slowpoke Rodriguez".